# Can't view Database Fields in CrystaReportViewer

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I have set up a crystalreport by using a dataset. After binding it to the crystalreportvewer I get no error, but the  database fields are simply not visible. I have done it in vs.net 2005, using C#. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should fill DataSet first. CrystalReportViewer can't fill your dataset automatically.